# WebApplicationContext vs ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-mvc

In my Spring-MMVC application,

I have a **xx-servlet.xml** corresponding to my dispatcher servlet- Defines my web layer beans/classes and importing another context.xml which defines all persistence layer bean/services.

In xx-servlet.xml,

have defined a `ApplicationContextProvider` class which implements `ApplicationcontextAware` interface.

and have annotated all my beans (presentation objects) with `@Component` and when needed getting the instance of these beans from `ApplicationContext` (not using `WebApplicationContext`).

So, in this case what would be the scope of my beans?

Also, What would be the case if I use `WebApplicationContext`?

What would be the best practice... use `ApplicationContext` or `WebApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebApplicationContext adds [more scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-scopes-other) (request, session, globalSession) to the standard Application context (which only provides Singleton and Prototype scopes). If you do not specify a bean scope it will be by default Singleton scope.

The best practice is if you are in a web environment you should be using WebApplicationContext so you can use those additional scopes and [ServletContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) beans. But if you don't use them then it's up to you.

Besides that, most spring mvc infrastructure beans need a WebApplicationContext.